# R3 Corda sharing transaction with multiple participants

Tags: corda

How to share the transaction between multiple participants in the network? say for an example A,B,C and D. where we want to share the transaction to all participants where A and D don't have option to edit the transaction further.

Answer (score 1):

There's two things you can do:

1. You can write the state object such that A, B, C and D are all listed as participants. However, the contract code for this state object should be written such that it only allows B and C to update the state object. An example might be a bilateral agreement between B and C but A and D are also listed as participants because they are regulators that should be see the whole transaction. If you go down this approach, it is important that the transactions are constructed such that only the public keys for A and D are listed in the commands and you hard code A and D in some other fields in the state so you can perform validation inside the contracts sandbox.

Example:

```
data class Example(
    val A: AbstractParty,
    val D: AbstractParty,
    override val participants: List<AbstractParty>,
    override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier()
) : LinearState {
    constructor (
        A: AbstractParty, 
        B: AbstractParty, 
        C: AbstractParty, 
        D: AbstractParty
    ) : this(A, D, listOf(A, B, C ,D))
}
```

2. You can use the new observable states feature in Corda V2, which allows an arbitrary number of nodes to observe the output states from a transaction. See an example here: https://github.com/roger3cev/observable-states. In this example, I create a crowd funding campaign, where only the campaign manager is the participant. However, the transaction is broadcast to all other parties on the same business network (so they can see the campaigns).

Option two is probably the better option. Cheers!

Comment: If you use this observable states approach, can observing node take action on the state data, such as making another transaction taking the shared data as an input?

Comment: No - the all the participants in the output states wouldn't necessarily know that there are any observers. Of course, the participants in the state that send the transaction to the observers would know, though. If you would like the observers to be able to create a transaction using a particular state as an input, then they will need to be a participant on that state object.

Comment: could you please elaborate more? it seems like one of the  observer node is using Campaign as an input to send a transaction back to the manager node in the observable states example.

Comment: Apologies, you are right. I actually wrote this app but forgot what it does! Indeed, I broadcast the campaign state to all nodes on the network, then they can use it as an input to another transaction. Note though, that the pledge transaction produces two states: campaign output and pledge output. The pledger and the campaign manager signs the pledge, ONLY the campaign manager signs the campaign state (it doesn't have the pledger as a participant so the contract has no reference as to what is a valid key, or not).